# Can't get this REGEX negative lookahead / lookaround working for JS

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Cannot get a simple negative look around working.

In this list of items, I do not want the ones with `Re:` at the start

```
Re: [PAID] need Composer for Film
[PAID] need Composer for Film
want composer for project
```

I actually got this working for stopping question marks at the end:

```
(?!(.*\?$))((create|after......
```

so it would not match the bottom result.

```
[PAID] need Composer for Film
want composer for project
need composer?
```

But just cannot get the same principle working for `Re:` at beginning.

```js
/(?!(^Re:.*$))((create|after|(attention|need|require?|want|seek)(s|ing|ed)*.?.?|(look|search)(ing|s|es)*( for| to work (with|for))( | an* ))(\w)*( ?)(film|movie|instrumental|original|background)*( ?)((?!(musician|composit|music video))(music|compos|(audio|sound)( ?)track|((theme)*( ?)(tune|song))|scor(e|ing)|jingle)))/ig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you are asking how to match an entire string - if the string does *not start with `Re:`*.

Using `Re:` within a negative lookahead, with the *Start of line anchor* `^` outside of the lookahead, and an *end of line anchor* within the lookahead, you get this:

```
/^(?!Re:.*$).*/gm
```

**[See it](https://regex101.com/r/0kFDXF/1)** in action on regex101

Comment: thanks alot!! however I cannot seem to add it with my current negative lookaheads for getting rid of questions. So basically when I add a "^" outside the brackets to add the "Re:" it breaks my other negative lookaheads, which are to have no question mark at end of string (or just before brackets) 
have a look:
https://regex101.com/r/LocGUI/2/